# Image Disabled Attribute in Chromium

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom, onclick

I am trying to disable the onClick handler of a simple image button but I cannot get it to work. I have added the "disabled" attribute on an img tag but even that does not work.

This seems to have changed in Chromoum some time after December 2022 but I do not know exactly when.

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" onClick="alert('TEST')" disabled>
```

No matter what i do the alert "TEST" appears.

jsFiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/4td0ouwb/

Expected the image to be "unclickable". Instead it is clickable and the onClick event fires.

Comment: `disabled` is not allowed on `<img>` elements. And that's just an image, not an "image button". _"The disabled attribute is supported by <button>, <fieldset>, <keygen>, <optgroup>, <option>, <select>, <textarea> and <input>."_

Comment: I guess my question is why this worked in previous versions of Chromium (december 2022) and worked in deprecated IE

Comment: @ZeroHero I looked at some Chromium commits and bug reports ([here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/da597edd8551e584314c377299c664e902605724), [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/bbd023d8fc7d4ad6e0049d3af5a6f5d29a426bdd), and [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1422263)) and it seems like they have been tweaking the behavior of `disabled` on mouse events recently. So it's possible the behavior you saw back in December was just a browser bug. But as mentioned before, the spec implies that `disabled` should have no effect on images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `disabled` attribute has no effect on HTML images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled#:%7E:text=The%20disabled%20attribute%20is%20supported%20by%20%3Cbutton%3E%2C%20%3Cfieldset%3E%2C%20%3Ckeygen%3E%2C%20%3Coptgroup%3E%2C%20%3Coption%3E%2C%20%3Cselect%3E%2C%20%3Ctextarea%3E%20and%20%3Cinput%3E.:%7E:text=The%20disabled%20attribute%20is%20supported%20by%20%3Cbutton%3E%2C%20%3Cfieldset%3E%2C%20%3Ckeygen%3E%2C%20%3Coptgroup%3E%2C%20%3Coption%3E%2C%20%3Cselect%3E%2C%20%3Ctextarea%3E%20and%20%3Cinput%3E.). Disabling an element's event handler depends on what JavaScript framework, if any, you are using. Generally though, the approach involves removing/deregistering the handler from the element.

However, if you really want to be able to use the `disabled` attribute, and you are able to make changes to the handler function, you could add an if statement that makes an early return if the attribute is present:

```js
function myAlert(elt, str) {
  if (elt.hasAttribute("disabled")) return;
  alert(str);
}
```

```css
img { display: block; }
```

```html
Not disabled:
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" onclick="myAlert(this, 'TEST')">

Disabled:
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" onclick="myAlert(this, 'TEST')" disabled>
```